# How to link a docker container with a node.js server

Tags: docker, aws-sam, aws-sam-cli

The command [`sam local start-lambda`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-cli-command-reference-sam-local-start-lambda.html) spins up a server inside a Docker container that emulates an AWS Lambda function:

```
$ sam local start-lambda
Starting the Local Lambda Service. You can now invoke your Lambda Functions defined in your template through the endpoint.
2020-05-29 12:32:13  * Running on http://127.0.0.1:3001/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
Fetching lambci/lambda:java8 Docker container image......
Mounting /private/var/folders/p_/0lzsyjqd64j3qynmw8sdmf2ws82gz7/T/tmp19t_696o as /var/task:ro,delegated inside runtime container
```

I wrote a simple Node.js server that hits this endpoint.

Now, i'd like to package both up (i.e. one would run `docker start` and both the node.js server & `sam local start-lambda` would start running), but i'm not sure how to do this.

Can I write a Dockerfile that somehow links these two endpoints?

Answer (score 2):

You can use Docker Compose to do that. https://docs.docker.com/compose/

You would create a service for lambda, and one for node and then configure each accordingly exposing the desired ports, etc., depending on exactly how you want to use them.

Comment: docker compose would create two containers, right? but `sam local start-lambda` already spins up a container...

Comment: Well, if you do it using Docker Compose then instead of starting lambda with sam, you would need to create the lambda service in Docker-compose, either using an existing build file for lambda, or creating one. Here's an article I found doing something similar: https://cbax.me/posts/2019/03/aws-sam-cli-inside-docker-compose/.  Hope that helps.